# How do I convert from String[] to ArrayList<String> using the BeanUtils.populate method?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, apache-commons-beanutils

How do I convert from String[] to ArrayList using the BeanUtils.populate method?  It looks like I could use the ArrayConverter class, but I'm having a hard time finding an explanation on how to do that.

Here is some test code I created:

```
public class TestAction {
public static TestBean testPopulate() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    TestBean bean = new TestBean();
    String[] names = {"teststring","testboolean","testinteger","testarray"};
    String[] array = {"hi","bye"};
    Object[] values = {"TEST","","100",array};
    int i = 0;
    while (i < names.length) {
        String name = names[i];
        map.put(name, values[i]);
        i++;
    }
    BeanUtils.populate(bean, map);

    return bean;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TestBean bean = testPopulate();
        System.out.println(bean.getTeststring() + " " + bean.getTestinteger() + " " + bean.getTeststring() + " " + bean.isTestboolean());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

public class TestBean {
private String teststring;
private boolean testboolean;
private int testinteger;
private ArrayList<String> testarray;

public String getTeststring() {
    return teststring;
}
public void setTeststring(String teststring) {
    this.teststring = teststring;
}
public boolean isTestboolean() {
    return testboolean;
}
public void setTestboolean(boolean testboolean) {
    this.testboolean = testboolean;
}
public int getTestinteger() {
    return testinteger;
}
public void setTestinteger(int testinteger) {
    this.testinteger = testinteger;
}
public ArrayList<String> getTestarray() {
    return testarray;
}
public void setTestarray(ArrayList<String> testarray) {
    this.testarray = testarray;
}

}
```

I pass in a String[] type expecting it to know how to convert to ArrayList, but it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general-purpose answer as I don't generally work with Beans.  It's possible BeanUtils *should* handle this case, but it would surprise me.

An array of Strings is not the same thing as an ArrayList object, despite their similarities.  It's generally a poor idea to implicitly convert from one to the other, as there are multiple logical ways that could be done.

- You can use [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) which takes an array and returns a wrapper `List` object.  Note that it is not an `ArrayList`, it is instead a fixed-size custom implementation of `List` which directly interfaces with the passed array, meaning no new storage has to be allocated.
- If instead you really do want an `ArrayList`, you can construct a new one based off the `List` object you got, with:

  ```
  ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
  ```

  This call *does* allocate a new storage array, but if you want adjustable-size, you have to accept that O(n) cost.

These two possible choices, both of which are equally valid depending on your use case, are exactly why it would be a poor idea for your bean to implicitly convert an array into a `List` - which implementation should it chose?  The fast one that throws exceptions if you try to resize it, or the slow one that doesn't?

Wherever possible, be explicit about your type conversions.  Despite the verbosity seeming/being obnoxious, this is one of Java's strongest features.

Comment: Ok I understand now.  I changed String[] to ArrayList<String> and the code ran with no errors.  BeanUtils purposely fails when converting from String[] to ArrayList<String>.  As a follow up question since the HttpServletRequest class in Java returns either String or String[] type, then does that force me to use only primitive types and String[] type in my bean?

Comment: Which method of `HttpServletRequest`?  It doesn't force you to, no, but if the type of data being passed around in the bean is a `String[]` it would probably make sense to use arrays in your bean, then convert them to `List` objects when you need to.  Alternatively, do some pre-processing.  Before passing the map to BeanUtils.populate, construct the `List` object you want to use, and put that in the map instead.

Comment: Ah...pre-processing is a good idea I will try that out.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention what exactly fails in your code but here is how to convert String array to list without any third party utilities:

`Arrays.asList(new String[] {"aaa", "bbb",  "ccc"})`